# VS2008 Startup, Environment, Options Dialog Box missing

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a new installation of VS2008 after a PC Rebuild and "Startup" does not appear under:  Tools|Options|Environment. It was there before the rebuild. Any ideas why it is missing and how to get it to appear? In particular I want to get VS to "Load last loaded solution" at startup.

Neville http://www.surfulater.com

Answer (score 2):

Check the 'Show All Settings' checkbox at the bottom-left of the dialog

Answer (score 0):

It was there all the time, I couldn't see the wood for the trees. Too early in the day for us Oz'ies.